# How to open a default Document library and upload files from it when clicking Choose file option?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

How to upload files from default Document Library when clicking on Choose file INPUT control?

When clicking on the "Choose file" it should open Document Library, from which I could select documents that would then be uploaded just like when you'd select files from your local drive.

[image]

Is it possible anyway?

Comment: You want to upload files _from_ a SharePoint library where they're already uploaded? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? 'Cause there may be a better way.

Comment: am doing one app where i suppose to select some documents from one library and upload them to another library and there are some operation which am doing through workflow